# Symfony2 Doctrine2 Relations m:n why when creating relation bt my form counter doesnt change?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm, entity-relationship

Hello here is my problem:
i got two entities:
Application Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Category", inversedBy="applications")
 */
private $categories;
/**
 * Add categories
 *
 * @param \ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Category $categories
 * @return Application
 */
public function addCategory(\ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
{
    $this->categories[] = $categories;
    $categories->addApplication($this);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove categories
 *
 * @param \ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Category $categories
 */
public function removeCategory(\ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
{
    $this->categories->removeElement($categories);
}
```

And Category Entity:

```
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="appsCount", type="integer")
 */
private $appsCount;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Application", mappedBy="categories")
 */
private $applications;


/**
 * Add applications
 *
 * @param \ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Application $applications
 * @return Category
 */
public function addApplication(\ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Application $applications)
{
    $this->addAppsCount(1);

    $this->applications[] = $applications;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove applications
 *
 * @param \ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Application $applications
 */
public function removeApplication(\ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Application $applications)
{
    $this->addAppsCount(-1);

    $this->applications->removeElement($applications);
}
/**
 * @param integer $appsCount
 * @return integer
 */
public function addAppsCount($appsCount)
{
    $this->appsCount += $appsCount;

    return $this;
}
```

and i have also form to add categories to my application entities
something like this:

```
$builder->add('categories', 'entity', array(
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'property' => 'namePl',
                'class'    => 'ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Category',
        ));
```

and when i add category to my application the counter doesnt change its always 0 (default value from controller) why is that ?
Controller action:
        $em = $this->getEntityManager();

```
    $applicationsRepo = $em->getRepository('ApplicationsBundle:Application');
    $application = $applicationsRepo->findOneByInName($inName);

    if (!$application) {
        $application = new Application($inName);
        $em->persist($application);
        $em->flush();
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new ApplicationType(), $application);

    $form->handleRequest($this->getRequest());

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($application);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin_applications_application_list'));
    }

    return array(
        'application' => $application,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    );
```

Comment: Do you save both entities after that ? We need your controller code.

Comment: it looks like it never gets into methods `addCategory()` and `addApplication` also for the record it does create the relations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case to make entity invoke method

```
public function addApplication(ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Application $applications)
{
    $this->addAppsCount(1);

    $this->applications[] = $applications;
    return $this;
}
```

i had to add parametr to my form builder:

```
$builder->add('categories', 'entity', array(
                'multiple' => true,
                'expanded' => true,
                'property' => 'namePl',
                'class'    => 'ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Category',
                'by_reference' => false,
        ));
```

how it works ? the form edits category field of application entity
by check boxes. it use `getCategories()` to display categories, when we check a category it creats relations beetwen them running method:

```
public function addCategory(\ApplicationsBundle\Entity\Category $categories)
{
    $this->categories[] = $categories;
    $categories->addApplication($this);

    return $this;
}
```

and this line is important:

```
    $categories->addApplication($this);
```

couse it add aplications to category.